# Delete graphs VBA Error

Tags: excel, graph, vba

How do I get VBA to ignore this code when there are no graphs on the worksheet? At the moment, unless there is a ChartObject in the worksheet, it will stop and open the debugger.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of ignoring the code, why not just ignore the error.

```
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 4):

> How do I get VBA to ignore this code when there are no graphs on the worksheet?

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Chrtobj As ChartObject

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Check if there are any chartobjects in the sheet
    If Not ws.ChartObjects.Count = 0 Then ws.ChartObjects.Delete
End Sub
```